# ¿Como hago un icono que aparezca sobre otras apps?

Tags: android

Hay un montón de aplicaciones que te dejan un icono sobre otras aplicaciones, como la calculadora y las notas de algunas versiones de android, que aparecen sobre el resto de aplicaciones. Esto es usado en aplicaciones como feh tools, mobizen y calcy, con la variante de que estas últimas solamente dejan un icono pequeño que ejecuta una función al pulsarlo, mientras las primeras dejan una ventanita.

¿Podríais decirme qué se usa para esto?

[EDIT] Gracias por decirme en qué no lo he explicado bien, Emerita.
Pongo como ejemplo esta imágen:[image: Por ejemplo]

Calcy es una aplicación que te deja un botón para que cuando lo pulses mientras juegas a pokémon go te salen unas stats ocultas del pokémon, sin embargo, este botón, se mantiene en todas las aplicaciones, abiertas o cerradas, hasta que cierras el servicio/aplicación que mantiene el icono.
En esta imagen, he puesto el icono de calcy sobre el icono de la play store para que se vea que es independiente al grid, esa bola roja con IV es el icono de Calcy.

Otros ejemplos: 
[FEH Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgUDA.png) 
[Mobizen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFVOG.png)

Comment: Gracias por votar. Ya que habéis votado negativamente, es de entender que es una pregunta muy obvia, así que: ¿Podríais responder ya de paso, o citarme donde se pregunta antes que aquí, ya que no lo encuentro?

Comment: O claro, si no es suficientemente comprehensible, comentar qué es lo que no he expuesto claro.

Comment: Yo no entendí tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que cuando se instala la app te pone el icono en el escritorio?. Pon si puedes una foto o algo similar de lo que estás buscando o queriendo explicar, así alguien entenderá lo que necesitas. Échale un ojo a [mcve]

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios. Aporto una captura con una de las aplicaciones mencionadas a la pregunta.
Si hace falta puedo agregar una de cada una de ellas sobre distintas aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo encontré:

https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256

Muchas gracias a todos por la atención prestada